# Validator.RenderControl returns an empty string

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, render

I've faced with following problem and fighting with it almost 2 days.
I have the following code.

```
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        string controlOutput;
        string validatorOutput;
        string allOutput;
        StringWriter controlStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter controlHtmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(controlStringWriter);

        StringWriter validatorsStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter validatorsHtmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(validatorsStringWriter);

        base.Render(controlHtmlWriter);
        controlOutput = controlStringWriter.ToString();

        this.renderValidators(validatorsHtmlWriter);
        validatorOutput = validatorsStringWriter.ToString();

        allOutput = String.Format("{0}&nbsp;{1}", controlOutput, validatorOutput);
        writer.Write(allOutput);
    }
```

The renderValidators function is :

```
  private void renderValidators(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (BaseValidator validator in this.ValidatorsCollection)
            {
                validator.RenderControl(writer);
            }
        }
```

The Render Function return an Empty String.
The Visible property of Validator that is in collection is set to true.

I am adding the validators in OnInit function. During first rendering validator.RenderControl(writer); return an empty string , after postback it starts to return an html input....

Maybe someone has faced with such problem ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding you need to check if the control has been added to a page before rendering the validator.

```
        Page page = Page;
        if (page == null || page.Request == null) {
            return false;
        }
```

A very helpful example can be found in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719624%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)